# C preprocessor Result

Tags: c, if-statement, header, c-preprocessor, ansi-c

Which result does return this construct? I mean the result variable in main-function, and why?
I know, that the example is very strange ;)

***header1.h file:***

```
extern const int clf_1;
```

***header2.c file:***

```
#include    "header1.h"
const  int clf_1 = 2;
```

***test.h file:***

```
#include <header1.h>
#define xyz clf_1
#define NC_CON 2    
#if (xyz== NC_CON)
#define test 40
#else
#define test 41
#endif
```

***C file***

```
#include <header1.h>
#include <test.h>
    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
       int result = 0:
        if (test == 40)
        {
             result  = 40;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Run `gcc -C -E yoursource.c` to find out

Comment: ye, I did it and the result is 41 but I expected 40 because  xyz == clf_1 and clf_1 == 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the wikipage on the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and the documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) (the preprocessor inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), i.e run by `gcc` or `g++` etc...). It is a textual thing, and it is run before the definition `const  int clf_1 = 2;`  has been processed by the compiler. A `#if` directive only makes sense if all the names appearing in it are *preprocessor symbols* (defined with `#define` or with `-D` passed on the command line of the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler)

Use `gcc -C -E yoursource.c > yoursource.i` (with some other options after `gcc`, probably `-I.` is needed ... you should `#include "header1.h"`
 etc...) then look with an editor or a pager into the generated `yoursource.i` (the preprocessed form)

<sup>The world would be very different if the C preprocessor transformed [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s; for historical reasons, the first C preprocessors were textual filters (run as a different program).</sup>